# Pass FrameLayout as part of android Messsage IPC

Tags: android, android-layout, ipc, android-framelayout

I have implemented a [Messenger](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services#Messenger) as IPC mechanism between two android apps. Now  I want to pass a FrameLayout object as part of android.os.Message

```
Message msg = new Message();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("4", "2");
msg.setData(bundle);
msg.what = 42;
msg.obj = a_frame_layout_instance;
```

I want to do this so that app1 can create a layout and inflate it, and then pass the layout object to app2 via IPC, which can then add/update the view.

This fails because FrameLayout is not parcelable.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't marshal non-Parcelable objects across processes.
```

1. Is there a way to pass a FrameLayout instance via IPC?
2. Is there some other path that can be explored so that app1 creates the views, and app2 updates the view?

Comment: Why pass framelayout to app2? Why not let app2 handle the creation of view whole you pass the data

Comment: @leeCoder Because app2 does not know how to completely inflate the entire view. It knows how to inflate some portion.